# How should I fetch payment intent secret for Stripe Elements in my Next.js app?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe payments in my Next.js app as described in the guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

The guide tells me that in order to use Stripe Elements for my checkout form, I need to know payment intent. It says:

> Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads

The issue is - our website will not have a separate payments page, the payment form will be displayed inside the modal, which is loaded on every page of the website. That means, I would have to fetch the payment intent for any user who ever visits any page on our website, whether they're planning to purchase the course or not, just so that I could display the payment form inside the modal. That doesn't seem right to me.

Can you give me some advice, let me know if there's a better way to handle this?

---

Another issue is that this guide tells me that I should pass the fetched payment intent `clientSecret` as an option to `<Elements/>` wrapper.

And if I hover on `<Elements/>` wrapper in my VSCdoe, it tells me:

> [...] Render an Elements provider at the root of your React app so that it is available everywhere you need it. [...]

So, does that mean I have to put `<Elements/>` wrapper into my `_app.tsx` file? And that means I'd have to fetch the payment intent `clientSecret` inside of the `_app.tsx`? So that my app would fetch payment intent secret any time any user ever loads any page on my website?

Again, this seems pretty weird, wouldn't it slow things down, add extra requests and loading time to all my pages, and create a whole bunch of payment intents that are never used?

Comment: Are you not able to defer the creation of the Payment Intent until the modal is invoked and then initiate the Elements instance? It's hard to give advice without code examples of how you handle this currently.

Comment: Also, it's just a recommendation that you render the `<Elements>` component at the root – not a requirement. As long as you're initialising Stripe.js (via `loadStripe`) globally across your site, you'll still benefit from the anti-fraud benefits Stripe.js brings (via Radar).

Answer (score 0):

Render the payment form in a modal in Layout.js and wrap the
entire project in the Layout component

place this code in _app.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import PaymentModalForm from "../components/PaymentModalForm"

const promise = loadStripe("pk_test_....")
// replace pk_test_... with your publishable key
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8000"
// replace API_URL with your backend server url

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const [secret, setSecret] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchSecret = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/create_intent`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 
                    items: [{ id: 'adidas boost', quantity: 2}]
                })
            })
            const { client_secret } = await response.json()
            setSecret(clientSecret)
        }
        fetchSecret()
    }, [])
    const options = {
        clientSecret: secret,
        appearance: { theme: "stripe"}
    }
    return (
        {secret && (
            <Elements stripe={promise} options={options}>
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
            </Elements>
        )}
    )
    
}

export default App
```

Then in your Layout.js, fill in this code

```
import PaymentModalForm from "../components/PaymentModalForm"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (showModal) {
            setShowModal(false)
        } else {
            setShowModal(true)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                {children}
                <button onClick={handleClick}>Show Payment Modal</button>
            </div>
            {showModal ? (
                <div className="modal fade">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <PaymentModalForm />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : ( null )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

There's more work to be done in PaymentModalForm.js